# What happens when you change the src of an img tag with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, caching

I tried looking this up in google but Im getting alot of turtorials on "how to" rather than what the side effects are.

When changing the src of an img, does this cause a double caching effect? What if someone had used jquery to create a slider/rotater/comic viewer/marquee/etc and had used jquery to do so?

On a mobile device, could the page stop working after the image rotates through with the device receiving some type of error similar to "page is too large?"

Could the images be cached in a way that that the browser remembers them? And by that I mean when you have an image with a specific name that you make an edit to and the browser loads a cached version of it. Could this cause false image loads if a randomizer code was placed to choose a random image?

I am just curious what kind of effects this could have on a browser by browser/visit by visit basis.

I wanted to test this, but I feel my results could be secluded or not broad enough to cover all scenarios when the knowledge may already be available.

This is purely for knowledge, not for a project. I figured someone else might wonder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the `src` attribute loads the new image.

Even though I would pre-load the image first, then replace or handle the image in that manner.

You can see a working example for both here: http://jsfiddle.net/je9w1n9m/

But I think your issue is more about how your caching headers are set-up for static content.  If you have caching headers set-up right on your web server to tell the browser to cache the static content, then the image will return a `304 Not Modified` response, and will be cached in the browser from the first time it loads.

Comment: So what your saying is changing the src does not actually affect the cache?

Comment: If you mean that if it doesn't affect the images that are already loaded on the page, then yes they are cached in the browser, depending if you have your response headers set-up.

Comment: In many of the new browsers, images are automatically cached for that session regardless of the headers, so regardless, I think you're safe. But check if you have static content caching set-up and you have expire tags, etc.

Comment: It's better explained here: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Between you and the article, I think Im square.